# Load test directory into the rebar3 shell

Tags: erlang, rebar, erlang-shell

When I boot up a `rebar3 shell` I can't access any of the modules in my `test/` directory. I would like to try out some of the helper functions I've written there, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

With rebar3 tests are run under the `test` [profile](https://www.rebar3.org/v3.0/docs/profiles), so run your shell with that profile:

```
rebar3 as test shell
```